# How to rotate the form in a vertical direction in c#

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form that contains different controls like MediaControl and Panel. I want to rotate my form in a vertical direction.

Any ideas please help me.

Comment: How do you rotate something in a vertical direction?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the contents(controls) X degrees to the right or left?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw vertical text on a form, here's how:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7282y7x%28VS.80%29.aspx

However, it sounds more like you want to rotate the entire form or controls.  Here's a similar question:

[Windows form rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399648/windows-form-rotation)

Basically this turns out to be very complicated.  You may have to make everything owner-drawn.

If it's possible to do this in WPF, it might be easier.